# Using try catch statements with the node.js URL module for URL validation

Tags: node.js

I'm parsing the URL input to a function using the [URL module](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html) in node.

If a relative path is given a `TypeError` is thrown. I'm using a `try...catch` statement to deal with this as shown below:

```
const { URL } = require('url');

try {
  const absolute = new URL('https://static.pexels.com/photos/126407/pexels-photo-126407.jpeg');
  console.log(absolute);
} catch (e) {
  if (e instanceof TypeError) {
    console.log('absolute is a relative path');
  } else {
    throw e;
  }
}

try {
  const relative = new URL('/images/picture.jpg');
  console.log(relative);
} catch (e) {
  if (e instanceof TypeError) {
    console.log('relative is a relative path');
  } else {
    throw e;
  }
}
```

Is this a legitimate use of try catch statements or am I abusing it somewhat? What's the correct way to do this if I am approaching it incorrectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically if you have a piece of code that might throw an error you should use a try catch block ... and to check whether it will throw any error you have to check the documentation.

Here as far as I know creating a URL throws an error so you have done well.

Also when you are catching an error you better log the error in a log-stream output ... it is better to log the information in a text file, also log the time,date and which part of the code is throwing the error as well.

**UPDATE:**

you can also write a module like `URLCreator.js` that handles the URL validation for you some think like this:

```
const {URL} = require(URL);
function createURL(givenURL, callback) {
    try {
        let myURL = new URL(givenURL);
        callback(myURL);
    } catch (e) {
        if (e instanceof TypeError) {
            //error handling procedure...
        } else {
            throw e;//cause we dont know what it is or we want to only handle TypeError
        }
    }
}

module.exports = createURL;
```

Comment: thanks for your input!

I'm expecting this error quite frequently because the vast majority of paths I'll get through will be relative. Would this be ground to avoid logging? My concern is getting type errors for other reasons and this not being seen on the front end.

for context, this code is living in a lambda function

Comment: if you are concerned about you are using it everywhere and you want it to be more clean ... try writing a module which simply handles the URL validation there you only need to call a method of that module and be sure that the error is handled inside it ...

Comment: I'm afraid my knowledge might not be deep enough to follow. Could you link me to documentation outlining why abstracting to a module is beneficial? It's the error being handled inside that I'm not following with.

Comment: I was going to abstract is as follows:

    `const validateUrl = (url) => {
      try {
        return new URL(url);
      } catch (e) {
        if (e instanceof TypeError) {
          return e;
        }
        throw e;
      }
    };`

Comment: I'm under 15 rep so it's not showing publicly. I have clicked it though!